# What's the shortcut key to jump to the end of a line in intellij idea 9?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

What's the shortcut key to jump to the end of a line in intellij idea?

I'm using Mac OS X version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cmd-right arrow

Comment: With a soft-wrapped line, this only moves to the soft wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Cmd-down works for several applications.

Answer (score 0):

Related: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows) jumps to the next empty line.